# When to use Common Table Expression (CTE)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have begun reading about *Common Table Expression* and cannot think of a use case where I would need to use them. They would seem to be redundant as the same can be done with derived tables. Is there something I am missing or not understanding well? Can someone give me a simple example of limitations with regular select, derived or temp table queries to make the case of CTE? Any simple examples would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

One example, if you need to reference/join the same data set multiple times you can do so by defining a CTE. Therefore, it can be a form of code re-use.

An example of self referencing is recursion: [Recursive Queries Using CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

For exciting Microsoft definitions
[Taken from Books Online:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

A CTE can be used to:

- Create a recursive query. For more information, see [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)
- Substitute for a view when the general use of a view is not required; that is, you do not have to store the definition in metadata.
- Enable grouping by a column that is derived from a scalar subselect, or a function that is either not deterministic or has external access.
- Reference the resulting table multiple times in the same statement.

Comment: Yep. You can't self join a derived table. Worth making the point that a self join on a CTE will still leave you with 2 separate invocations of it though.

Comment: @Martin - I am surprised. Can you back up that statement?

Comment: @John Thanks, I am finding http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml quite useful too

Comment: @cyberkiwi - Which bit? That a self join will lead to 2 different invocations? See the example in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362043/sql-server-row-present-in-one-query-missing-in-another/3362307#3362307

Comment: Interesting fact about CTE. I always wondered why NEWID() in the CTE changes when the CTE is referenced more than once. `select top 100 * into #tmp from master..spt_values order by 1,2,3,4 select A.number, COUNT(*) from #tmp A inner join #tmp B ON A.number =  B.number+1 group by A.number` vs `with CTE AS (select top 100 * from master..spt_values order by 1,2,3,4) select A.number, COUNT(*) from CTE A inner join CTE B ON A.number = B.number+1 group by A.number`

Answer (score 60):

I use them to break up complex queries, especially complex joins and sub-queries. I find I'm using them more and more as 'pseudo-views' to help me get my head around the intent of the query.

My only complaint about them is they cannot be re-used. For example, I may have a stored proc with two update statements that could use the same CTE. But the 'scope' of the CTE is the first query only.

Trouble is, 'simple examples' probably don't really need CTE's!

Still, very handy.

Comment: ok. Can you make case with some relatively complex example that can help my head around this concept?

Comment: "My only complaint about them is they cannot be re-used" -- a CTE that you want to re-use should be considered a candidate for a `VIEW` :)

Comment: @onedaywhen: Understood, but that implies a global-scope I'm not always comfortable with. Sometimes within the scope of a proc I'd like to define a CTE and use it for selects and updates, or selects of similar data from different tables.

Comment: When I need the same CTE more than once, I feed it into a temporary table and then use the temporary table as much as I want.

Answer (score 50):

There are two reasons I see to use cte's.

To use a calculated value in the where clause. This seems a little cleaner to me than a derived table.

Suppose there are two tables - Questions and Answers joined together by Questions.ID = Answers.Question_Id (and quiz id)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    Select Question_Text,
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM Answers A WHERE A.Question_ID = Q.ID) AS Number_Of_Answers
    FROM Questions Q
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE Number_Of_Answers > 0
```

Here's another example where I want to get a list of questions and answers. I want the Answers to be grouped with the questions in the results.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT [Quiz_ID] 
      ,[ID] AS Question_Id
      ,null AS Answer_Id
          ,[Question_Text]
          ,null AS Answer
          ,1 AS Is_Question
    FROM [Questions]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Q.[Quiz_ID]
      ,[Question_ID]
      ,A.[ID] AS  Answer_Id
      ,Q.Question_Text
          ,[Answer]
          ,0 AS Is_Question
        FROM [Answers] A INNER JOIN [Questions] Q ON Q.Quiz_ID = A.Quiz_ID AND Q.Id = A.Question_Id
)
SELECT 
    Quiz_Id,
    Question_Id,
    Is_Question,
    (CASE WHEN Answer IS NULL THEN Question_Text ELSE Answer END) as Name
FROM cte    
GROUP BY Quiz_Id, Question_Id, Answer_id, Question_Text, Answer, Is_Question 
order by Quiz_Id, Question_Id, Is_Question Desc, Name
```

Comment: Can't your first example be simplified down to just use a nested query instead of the CTE?

Comment: Both examples could be.

Comment: You should've added the first one without the CTE, then it's immediately apparent why is the latter useful.

Comment: `HAVING` is another way to do a late-stage filter which can be similar to using a sub-`SELECT`

Answer (score 27):

One of the scenarios I found useful to use CTE is when you want to get DISTINCT rows of data based on one or more columns but return all columns in the table. With a standard query you might first have to dump the distinct values into a temp table and then try to join them back to the original table to retrieve the rest of the columns or you might write an extremely complex partition query that can return the results in one run but in most likelihood, it will be unreadable and cause performance issue.

But by using CTE (as answered by Tim Schmelter on [Select the first instance of a record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064473/select-the-first-instance-of-a-record))

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT myTable.*
    , RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY patientID ORDER BY ID)
    FROM myTable 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

As you can see, this is much easier to read and maintain. And in comparison to other queries, is much better at performance.

Answer (score 23):

Perhaps its more meaningful to think of a CTE as a substitute for a view used for a single query. But doesn't require the overhead, metadata, or persistence of a formal view. Very useful when you need to:

- Create a recursive query.
- Use the CTE's resultset more than once in your query.
- Promote clarity in your query by reducing large chunks of identical subqueries.
- Enable grouping by a column derived in the CTE's resultset

Here's a cut-and-paste example to play with:

```
WITH [cte_example] AS (
SELECT 1 AS [myNum], 'a num' as [label]
UNION ALL
SELECT [myNum]+1,[label]
FROM [cte_example]
WHERE [myNum] <=  10
)
SELECT * FROM [cte_example]
UNION
SELECT SUM([myNum]), 'sum_all' FROM [cte_example]
UNION
SELECT SUM([myNum]), 'sum_odd' FROM [cte_example] WHERE [myNum] % 2 = 1
UNION
SELECT SUM([myNum]), 'sum_even' FROM [cte_example] WHERE [myNum] % 2 = 0;
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 8):

Today we are going to learn about Common table expression that is a new feature which was introduced in SQL server 2005  and available in later versions as well.

Common table Expression :- Common table expression can be defined as a temporary result set or in other words its a substitute of views in SQL Server. Common table expression is only valid in the batch of statement where it was defined and cannot be used in other sessions.

Syntax of declaring CTE(Common table expression) :-

```
with [Name of CTE]
as
(
Body of common table expression
)
```

Lets take an example :-

```
CREATE TABLE Employee([EID] [int] IDENTITY(10,5) NOT NULL,[Name] [varchar](50) NULL)

insert into Employee(Name) values('Neeraj')
insert into Employee(Name) values('dheeraj')
insert into Employee(Name) values('shayam')
insert into Employee(Name) values('vikas')
insert into Employee(Name) values('raj')

CREATE TABLE DEPT(EID INT,DEPTNAME VARCHAR(100))
insert into dept values(10,'IT')
insert into dept values(15,'Finance')
insert into dept values(20,'Admin')
insert into dept values(25,'HR')
insert into dept values(10,'Payroll')
```

I have created two tables employee and Dept and inserted 5 rows in each table. Now I would like to join these tables and create a temporary result set to use it further.

```
With CTE_Example(EID,Name,DeptName)
as
(
select Employee.EID,Name,DeptName from Employee 
inner join DEPT on Employee.EID =DEPT.EID
)
select * from CTE_Example
```

Lets take each line of the statement one by one and understand.

To define CTE we write "with" clause, then we give a name to the table expression, here I have given name as "CTE_Example"

Then we write "As" and enclose our code in two brackets (---),  we can join multiple tables in the enclosed brackets.

In the last line, I have used "Select * from CTE_Example" , we are referring the Common table expression in the last line of code, So we can say that Its like a view, where we are defining and using the view in a single batch and CTE is not stored in the database as an permanent object. But it behaves like a view. we can perform delete and update statement on CTE and that will have direct impact on the referenced table those are being used in CTE. Lets take an example to understand this fact.

```
With CTE_Example(EID,DeptName)
as
(
select EID,DeptName from DEPT 
)
delete from CTE_Example where EID=10 and DeptName ='Payroll'
```

In the above statement we are deleting a row from CTE_Example and it will delete the data from the referenced table "DEPT" that is being used in the CTE.

Comment: I still don't get the point. What's the difference between this and just deleting from DEPT with exactly the same condition? It doesn't seem to make anything easier.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the execution plan may be different, and I think that is Neeraj's point, that there are many ways to achieve the same objective, but some will have advantages over others depending on the situation. For instance, it might be easier to read a CTE over a DELETE FROM statement in some circumstances, also the reverse might be true in others. Performance might improve or worsen. etc.

Answer (score 8):

It is very useful when you want to perform an "ordered update".

MS SQL does not allow you to use ORDER BY with UPDATE, but with help of CTE you can do it that way:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT TOP(5000) message_compressed, message, exception_compressed, exception
    FROM logs
    WHERE Id >= 5519694 
    ORDER BY Id
)
UPDATE  cte
SET     message_compressed = COMPRESS(message), exception_compressed = COMPRESS(exception)
```

Look here for more info: [How to update and order by using ms sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655010/how-to-update-and-order-by-using-ms-sql)

Answer (score 3):

One point not pointed out yet, is the **speed**. I know it's an old answered question, but I think this deserves direct comment/answer:

> They would seem to be redundant as the same can be done with derived tables

When I used CTE the very first time I was absolutely stunned by it's speed. It was a case like from a textbook, very suitable for CTE, but in *all* ocurences I ever used CTE, there was a significant speed gain. My first query was complex with derived tables, taking long minutes to execute. With CTE it took fractions of seconds and left me shocked, that it is even possible.

Answer (score -3):

```
 ;with cte as
  (
  Select Department, Max(salary) as MaxSalary
  from test
  group by department
  )  
  select t.* from test t join cte c on c.department=t.department 
  where t.salary=c.MaxSalary;
```

try this