# Select the first instance of a record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table, `myTable` that has two fields in it `ID` and `patientID`.  The same patientID can be in the table more than once with a different ID.  How can I make sure that I get only `ONE` instance of every `patientID`.?

EDIT: I know this isn't perfect design, but I need to get some info out of the database and today and then fix it later.

Comment: Are there any criteria to decide which record to return or do you want to return any one at random?

Comment: `top 1` only returns one record.  I need exactly one instance of every patient ID.  It doesn't matter which tblClaims.id is left out.

Comment: Then solution using a CTE is the way to go

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use a `CTE` with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT myTable.*
    , RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY patientID ORDER BY ID)
    FROM myTable 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: I would upvote this answer ten times if it was possible.

Comment: Good answer @TimSchmelter.

The same output can also be achieved using a sub-query:

`select * from (
 SELECT myTable.*
 , RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY patientID ORDER BY ID)
 FROM myTable 
) as myPatient where RN = 1`

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT patientID FROM myTable
```

you can get the same "effect" with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT patientID FROM myTable GROUP BY patientID
```

Comment: Not exactly.  The patient ID can show up in the table more than once with a diffierent tblclaims.id.  So if i select distinct, that makes that I get that patientID returned more than once

Comment: @wootscootinboogie only if you add more fields to the projections you're selecting. `DISTINCT` of only `patientID` should give you what you need. if you do `DISTINCT patiendID, ID` then yes, you will get distinct combinations thus more than one `patientID`

Answer (score -1):

The simple way would be to add `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query.  This will ensure only a single row is returned in the result set.

Comment: it's `SELECT TOP 1 ... ` in MSSQL

Comment: @PavelVeller: But i assume that `TOP 1` is not what OP is looking for. He want just one record for _every_ different patientID.

Comment: Okay, so LIMIT is available in MySQL and Drizzle, but doesn't SQL Server have something to similar effect?  In fact it does, in a roundabout way.  You can set up your query in a subquery using `ROW_NUMBER()`, and then limit the selection using the generated row numbers.  Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserver/archive/2006/10/25/limit-in-sql-server.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT tableName.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY patientID ORDER BY patientID) As 'Position' FROM  tableName
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE
Position = 1
```