# Select distinct the latest rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I select the latest rows not duplicated?

```
select distinct FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Kurier.id, FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Zlecenie.adresKoncowy, FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier.id
from FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Kurier 
join FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier on FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Kurier.id= FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier.kurierId
join FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Zlecenie on FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Zlecenie.id= FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier.zlecenieId
where FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Kurier.id = FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier.kurierId 
order by FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier.id desc
```

Here is my result from the above:

```
3   Gdynia      6
2   Katowice    5
2   Gdynia      4
2   Gdynia      3
2   Poznań      2
3   Warszawa    1
```

I want to keep first two rows of the above, where first is defined as having the maximum value in column 3:

```
3   Gdynia      6
2   Katowice    5
```

Comment: I want to select the latest distict from the first column (FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Kurier.id)

I want to keep first two rows:

Comment: Try to combine your query with what is found here, 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064473/select-the-first-instance-of-a-record'

Comment: @DaleK Yes, this is my definition. I want to get "first" 2 rows with the Max value in the third column :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, let me introduce you to table aliases - see how much easier your query is to read.

Now you can solve your problem using the `row_number()` function and then only selecting row numbers 1.

```
with cte as (
  select K.id Col1, Z.adresKoncowy Col2, ZK.id Col3
    , row_number() over (partition by K.id order by ZK.id desc) RowNum
  from FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Kurier K 
  join FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier ZK on K.id = ZK.kurierId
  join FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Zlecenie Z on Z.id = ZK.zlecenieId
  where K.id = ZK.kurierId 
  -- order by ZK.id desc
)
select Col1, Col2, Col3
from cte
where RowNum = 1
order by Col1 desc;
```

Note: Do use better column aliases than I have - I don't know what your columns represent but you do.

Comment: Yea, This is a much easier query. But I have following errors:
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'RowNum'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'Col1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'Col2'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'Col3'.

Comment: @Kipero sorry missed the `from` - see edit.

Comment: Wow man this :) I've had almost perfect result. I've got 2 rows but with the minimum value of third column. How can I solve it to the maximum?

Comment: @Kipero check the docs for the row_number function and teach yourself how it works and then modify it to give you the correct row. Better you start teaching yourself at this stage :)

Answer (score -1):

This should work :)

```sql
select FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Kurier.id, FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Zlecenie.adresKoncowy, max(FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier.id) from FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Kurier join FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier on FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Kurier.id= FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier.kurierId join FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Zlecenie on FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Zlecenie.id= FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier.zlecenieId where FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Kurier.id = FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier.kurierId 
Group by FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Kurier.id,FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Zlecenie.adresKoncowy
order by FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier.id
```

Comment: Woo! What a mess! Please check out the code formatting option.

Comment: Sorry for the messy code. Are you looking for the biggest FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier.id and FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Zlecenie.adresKoncowy for FirmaTransportowa.dbo.Kurier.id ?

Comment: Thank you for your response but I got following error:
Column "FirmaTransportowa.dbo.ZlecenieKurier.id" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: You can remove it. You dont need it anymore, the max() function replace it :)

Comment: @Ivan for a good answer, please provide some explanation of what you are doing rather than just a (messy) code dump. That way the OP learns how to do it themselves.