# SQL multiple alias in subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a setup where I would like to support a user defined subquery inside of a spatial query to identify overlapping polygons.  Below is an example:

```
SELECT i1.id, i2.id
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM Images WHERE id > 600) i1,
    (SELECT * FROM Images WHERE id > 600) i2
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(i1.footprint_latlon, i2.footprint_latlon) = TRUE
AND i1.id > i2.id
```

The above is working, but I more canonical way to do this exists.

The inner query is completely arbitrary here and the important component is that I am defining `i1` and `i2` using an identical query.  I am doing this so that I have `i1` and `i2` aliases for the outer, spatial query.

Is it necessary to execute the inner query twice or does a better way to create the `i1`, and `i2` aliases exist? Lots of example on executing subqueries with a single (mandatory alias), but I am not seeing any examples of 'multi-aliases'.

Comment: It is merely your ability to get experts to answer your question that causes you to raise these questions. There are thousands of examples, only if you spend time you can learn.

Comment: Even with `WITH i AS (foo) SELECT bah FROM i AS i1, i AS i2 WHERE...` the sub query is effectively resolved twice.  To avoid that YOU need to preserve the result, such as with a temp table.  But doing so may not be a good idea; you need to write the results somewhere and lose the indexes, etc. For that reason caching the results may be more expensive than resolving it twice. Also, note that sql is a declarative language and the rdbms is free to rearrange the execution, so as to make use of indexes, etc. In short, don't prematurely optimise. Be concerned with maintainable code.

Comment: @MatBailie I very much appreciate the point about premature optimization and the nature of SQL withr espect to how the query is performed. Interesting to know that indices are stripped, but that makes total sense once you highlighted that issue.

Comment: @Jzl5325 No, the indices are not *stripped* (what is that?) The CTE is executed *exactly once*, and every time the CTE is referenced, its (materialized) result set is used. And: this resultset  has no (sub)structure, at most it will have a defined order. [see my answer on how to *avoid* the CTE]

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks! Makes sense.  I am reading about CTE right now and trying out each of the answers to make sure I understand how they are working. By stripped, I mean removed and not used, but it sounds like that is not the case.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740748/when-to-use-common-table-expression-cte) looks to be pretty good for filling in my knowledge gap on a CTE.

Comment: @wildplasser - My comment noted that if the OP persists the intermediate results ***such as with a temp table*** then he would ***lose the indexes***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a clean easy way to "alias an alias". You could do something like this:

```
WITH 
   i1 AS (SELECT * FROM Images WHERE id > 600),
   i2 AS (SELECT * FROM i1)
SELECT i1.id, i2.id
FROM
    i1, i2
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(i1.footprint_latlon, i2.footprint_latlon) = TRUE
AND i1.id > i2.id
```

**EDIT**
and much nicer, as suggested by @MatBailie :

```
WITH 
   i AS (SELECT * FROM Images WHERE id > 600)
SELECT i1.id, i2.id
FROM
    i AS i1, i AS i2
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(i1.footprint_latlon, i2.footprint_latlon) = TRUE
AND i1.id > i2.id
```

Comment: `WITH i AS (foo) SELECT bah FROM i AS i1, i AS i2 WHERE...`

Comment: @MatBailie - nice improvement to my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

My inclination would be one of the following:

```
select i1.id, i2.id
from images i1 join
     images i2
     on st_intersects(i1.footprint_latlon, i2.footprint_latlon)
where i1.id > 600 and i2.id > i1.id;
```

Or:

```
with ix as (
      select i.*
      from images i
      where i.id > 600
     )
select i1.id, i2.id
from ix AS i1 join
     ix AS i2
     on st_intersects(i1.footprint_latlon, i2.footprint_latlon)
where i2.id > i1.id;
```

I don't think there is a shortcut on performing the self join.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to repeat the (complicated) subquery, you could either use a CTE (see Gordon Linoff's answer) or use a (temp) view containing the subquery
[a CTE behaves differently for the optimiser/planner, for larger resultsets  this could cause subobtimal performance] :

---

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW vv AS
     -- Put your complex subquery here ...
SELECT * FROM Images WHERE id > 600
        ;

SELECT i1.id, i2.id
FROM vv i1
JOIN vv i2 ON ST_INTERSECTS(i1.footprint_latlon, i2.footprint_latlon)
AND i1.id > i2.id
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i1.id, i2.id
FROM Images i1,Images i2, 
WHERE i2.id > 600
  AND i1.id > i2.id
  AND ST_INTERSECTS(i1.footprint_latlon, i2.footprint_latlon) = TRUE
```

Comment: This totally misses the point of the question. `The inner query is completely arbitrary here and the important component is that I am defining i1 and i2 using an identical query.`