# creating a temp table from a "with table as" CTE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I cannot seem to access a temp table based on the results of a CTE expression.

how do you create a temp table, and access the temp declared within a CTE.

in the example below, the last line will throw an error.

Thanks

```
 DECLARE @tbl TABLE
  ( 
   Id int
  ,ParentId int
  )
INSERT  INTO @tbl
        ( Id, ParentId )
select t_package.package_id, t_package.parent_ID from t_package 
;
WITH  abcd
        AS (
              -- anchor
            SELECT   id
                    ,ParentID
                    ,CAST(id AS VARCHAR(100)) AS [Path]
                    ,0 as depth
            FROM    @tbl
            WHERE   ParentId = 0
            UNION ALL
              --recursive member
            SELECT  t.id
                   ,t.ParentID
                   ,CAST(a.[Path] + ',' + CAST( t.ID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS varchar(100)) AS [Path]
                   ,a.depth +1
            FROM    @tbl AS t
                    JOIN abcd AS a ON t.ParentId = a.id
           )
SELECT * from abcd;

insert into #TMP (id,parent,branch,depth) (select * from abcd)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A set of CTEs introduced by a `WITH` clause is valid for *the* single statement that follows the last CTE definition. Here, it seems you should just skip the bare `SELECT` and make the `INSERT` the following statement:

```
WITH  abcd
        AS (
              -- anchor
            SELECT   id
                    ,ParentID
                    ,CAST(id AS VARCHAR(100)) AS [Path]
                    ,0 as depth
            FROM    @tbl
            WHERE   ParentId = 0
            UNION ALL
              --recursive member
            SELECT  t.id
                   ,t.ParentID
                   ,CAST(a.[Path] + ',' + CAST( t.ID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS varchar(100)) AS [Path]
                   ,a.depth +1
            FROM    @tbl AS t
                    JOIN abcd AS a ON t.ParentId = a.id
           )
insert into #TMP (id,parent,branch,depth) select * from abcd

select * from #TMP
```

(I've added the `select` from `#TMP` so that we still get a result set returned to the client, albeit that the `insert` and `select` statements are now reversed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 statement of CTE one by one, CTE will run just after declaration.  See the rule of [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

So remove `SELECT * from abcd;` before this 
`insert into #TMP (id,parent,branch,depth) (select * from abcd)`.

For Recursive CTE :[When to use Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740748/when-to-use-common-table-expression-cte)

Answer (score 0):

As a CTE is not persisted you can only use it once so once e.g.

```
WITH cte(id) AS 
(
SELECT 1
)

SELECT * FROM cte;

SELECT * FROM cte;
```

Would return the results '1' for the first call but then error with

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 Invalid object name 'cte'.

on the second.

You need to remove the

`SELECT * from abcd;`

before you populate your temp table or if you need to call it twice use a persisted method (temp table, table variable etc)