# Pull top percent of IDs from a list based off of another CTE percentage

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, percentage

I have the below CTE to pull in membership then to pull in all claims for those members ( if they had a claim hit within the date parameters) , now from the total membership (=1961) I need to pull in the TOP 3% or 0.03 from the claims CTE. I see 1961*0.03 is rounded to 59, so I need to pull in the top (59) Medicaid IDs from Claims with the highest total of claims utilization .

So for example in the **number_to_pull** CTE that gives what lines need to pull in ( it gives the 3% of membership ), then in the **sum_of_claims** CTE I want to ONLY pull in the top 3% Medicaid IDs from **Claims** CTE.. Since the membership can change depending on the date parms I want the **sum_of_claims** to have something like the below but I am not sure how to get started

End result is I will have a list top (3%)  of Medicaid IDs who have the most hits per claim for the date span called out

I need something like this, but I want it to pull in whatever the number is in the **number_to_pull** CTE and then to pull That number based off of the sum of claims.

```
Select Top ( select 
            round(count(mt.medicaid_no)*0.03) as percentt
      from membership mt)   

    cll.medicaid_no
   ,count(distinct claim_number) as sum_of_claims 

from claims cll

Group by cll.medicaid_no 

) select * from sum_of_claims
```

This is what my codes actually looks like

```
WITH 

DATES AS 
(
select  TRUNC(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'y')-1,'y') as startdate,         
 TRUNC(SYSDATE,'y')-1 as enddate

 from dual

),

membership as  (
select Distinct
 mbr.medicaid_no
,mbd.memb_dim_id
,mbd.memb_demographics_full_date

from dw.fact_member_demographics mbd

    inner join dates d
      on 1=1

inner join dw.DIM_MEMBER mbr
on mbd.memb_dim_id = mbr.memb_dim_id  

Where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM mbd.memb_demographics_full_date)= extract(year from d.startdate)
and mbd.company_dim_id in ('575')
      and mbd.age > 18

) ---select * from membership

,number_to_pull as ( 

  select 
            round(count(mt.medicaid_no)*0.03) as percentt
      from membership mt     
)  ---select * from top_number

,Claims as (

select 
 mbdd.medicaid_no
,mbdd.memb_dim_id
,dc.company_desc
,cl.primary_svc_date
,cl.claim_number
,case when cl.io_flag_dim_id = '1' then 'Inpatient'
      when cl.io_flag_dim_id = '2' then 'Outpatient' else 'false' end as In_Op
,cl.admit_type
,proc.procedure_code
,dx1.diagnosis_code as dx1
,dx1.diagnosis_short_desc as dx1desc
,dx2.diagnosis_code as dx2
,dx2.diagnosis_short_desc as dx2desc
,dx3.diagnosis_code as dx3
,dx3.diagnosis_short_desc as dx3desc
,dx4.diagnosis_code as dx4
,dx4.diagnosis_short_desc as dx4desc
,dx5.diagnosis_code as dx5
,dx5.diagnosis_short_desc as dx5desc
,bt.inp_outp_ind 



from membership mbdd



left join dw.fact_claim  cl
on mbdd.memb_dim_id = cl.memb_dim_id


inner join dates d
 on 1=1


inner join dw.DIM_PROCEDURE_CODE  proc
 on cl.cpt_code_dim_id = proc.procedure_dim_id

inner join dw.DIM_DIAGNOSIS dx1
 on cl.diagnosis_1_dim_id = dx1.diagnosis_dim_id 

inner join dw.DIM_DIAGNOSIS dx2
 on cl.diagnosis_2_dim_id = dx2.diagnosis_dim_id 

inner join dw.DIM_DIAGNOSIS dx3
 on cl.diagnosis_3_dim_id = dx3.diagnosis_dim_id 

inner join dw.DIM_DIAGNOSIS dx4
 on cl.diagnosis_4_dim_id = dx4.diagnosis_dim_id 

inner join dw.DIM_DIAGNOSIS dx5
 on cl.diagnosis_5_dim_id  = dx5.diagnosis_dim_id 

inner join dw.DIM_BILL_TYPE bt
 on cl.bill_type_dim_id = bt.bill_type_dim_id

inner join dw.DIM_COMPANY dc
 on cl.company_dim_id = dc.company_dim_id


Where cl.primary_svc_date between d.startdate and d.enddate
and cl.company_dim_id in ('575')
and CL.WHOLE_CLAIM_STATUS_DIM_ID IN  (1,2) 
and cl.io_flag_dim_id in ('1','2')
) ---select * from  claims

,sum_of_claims AS ( 

Select   
            ---- this is where I want to pull in the top 3% based off of membeship and sum of claims per Medicaid 
    cll.medicaid_no
   ,count(distinct claim_number) as sum_of_claims 

from claims cll

Group by cll.medicaid_no 

) select * from sum_of_claims
```

The end result I want is a list of Medicaid IDs and there total sum of claims, but this list will ONLY be the top 59 lines (3%)

```
MEDICAID_NO   SUM_OF_CLAIMS
111111         $12,439.61 
333333         $5,315.57 
444444         $2,007.00 
555555         $1,823.98 
888888         $1,770.00 
777777         $1,211.47 
9999999        $1,157.61 
6666666        $1,068.76
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results are really helpful.

Comment: added Oracle tag based on the syntax

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the end result .

Comment: What is a CTE stands for?

Comment: @oreh [Common Table Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4740748/230471), i.e. a `with` clause.

Comment: thx. I was thinking about a medicine term)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks David F. I was able to pull in the top 3% members from claims . Below is my code .

```
WITH 

DATES AS 
(
select  TRUNC(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'y')-1,'y') as startdate,         
 TRUNC(SYSDATE,'y')-1 as enddate

 from dual

),

membership as  (
select Distinct
 mbr.medicaid_no
,mbd.memb_dim_id
,mbd.memb_demographics_full_date



from dw.fact_member_demographics mbd


    inner join dates d
      on 1=1

 inner join dw.DIM_MEMBER mbr
  on mbd.memb_dim_id = mbr.memb_dim_id  

Where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM mbd.memb_demographics_full_date)= extract(year from d.startdate)
  and mbd.company_dim_id in ('575')
  and mbd.age > 18

) ---select * from membership

,Claims as (

select 
 mbdd.medicaid_no
,mbdd.memb_dim_id
,dc.company_desc
,cl.primary_svc_date
,cl.claim_number
,case when cl.io_flag_dim_id = '1' then 'Inpatient'
      when cl.io_flag_dim_id = '2' then 'Outpatient' else 'false' end as In_Op
,cl.admit_type
,proc.procedure_code
,dx1.diagnosis_code as dx1
,dx1.diagnosis_short_desc as dx1desc
,dx2.diagnosis_code as dx2
,dx2.diagnosis_short_desc as dx2desc
,dx3.diagnosis_code as dx3
,dx3.diagnosis_short_desc as dx3desc
,dx4.diagnosis_code as dx4
,dx4.diagnosis_short_desc as dx4desc
,dx5.diagnosis_code as dx5
,dx5.diagnosis_short_desc as dx5desc
,bt.inp_outp_ind
,cl.net_amt 



from membership mbdd


left join dw.fact_claim  cl
on mbdd.memb_dim_id = cl.memb_dim_id


inner join dates d
 on 1=1

inner join dw.DIM_PROCEDURE_CODE  proc
 on cl.cpt_code_dim_id = proc.procedure_dim_id


inner join dw.DIM_DIAGNOSIS dx1
 on cl.diagnosis_1_dim_id = dx1.diagnosis_dim_id 

inner join dw.DIM_DIAGNOSIS dx2
 on cl.diagnosis_2_dim_id = dx2.diagnosis_dim_id 

inner join dw.DIM_DIAGNOSIS dx3
 on cl.diagnosis_3_dim_id = dx3.diagnosis_dim_id 


inner join dw.DIM_DIAGNOSIS dx4
 on cl.diagnosis_4_dim_id = dx4.diagnosis_dim_id 


inner join dw.DIM_DIAGNOSIS dx5
 on cl.diagnosis_5_dim_id  = dx5.diagnosis_dim_id 


inner join dw.DIM_BILL_TYPE bt
 on cl.bill_type_dim_id = bt.bill_type_dim_id

inner join dw.DIM_COMPANY dc
 on cl.company_dim_id = dc.company_dim_id


Where cl.primary_svc_date between d.startdate and d.enddate
and cl.company_dim_id in ('575')
and CL.WHOLE_CLAIM_STATUS_DIM_ID IN  (1,2) -- pulling in only paid claims -- use whole claim
and cl.io_flag_dim_id in ('1','2')
) ---select * from  claims

,sum_of_claims AS ( 

Select 

    cll.medicaid_no
   ,sum(distinct cll.net_amt) as sum_of_claims 

from claims cll

Group by cll.medicaid_no 

) 
  ----- this is the new part added below

SELECT medicaid_no, sum_of_claims FROM (
    SELECT sh.medicaid_no, sh.sum_of_claims, COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_cnt
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY sh.sum_of_claims DESC ) AS rn
      FROM sum_of_claims sh
) 


 Where (rn)<(SELECT round(count(medicaid_no)*0.03) as percentt
                               from membership)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question, correctly, you want to get the top 3% here? This is the final query:

```
select * from sum_of_claims;
```

I think you want to replace this with something like the following:

```
SELECT medicaid_no, sum_of_claims FROM (
    SELECT medicaid_no, sum_of_claims, COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_cnt
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY sum_of_claims DESC ) AS rn
      FROM sum_of_claims
) WHERE rn <= 0.03 * total_cnt;
```

This will get the "top" 3% of records (where "top" is defined as those with the greatest claim amounts).

By the way, I find it hard to believe that this is what you want:

```
,count(distinct claim_number) as sum_of_claims
```

That wouldn't give a sum at all!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! and yeah this is my fault the title is misleading "sum of claims" is mislaeding I know all I am doing is counting the claims  hits per medicaid ID, if I wanted sum I would do ,sum(distinct cll.net_amt) as sum_of_claims... and Thank you again going to give it a try

Comment: So I did use the code and it worked perfectly! but the Row Number will need to be define by the number in the **number_to_pull** CTE since in that CTE it gives the total top number to pull in .  Since not sure how to do that I tried doing something like this

Comment: `SELECT medicaid_no, sum_of_claims FROM (
    SELECT medicaid_no, sum_of_claims, COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_cnt
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY sum_of_claims DESC ) AS rn
      FROM sum_of_claims
) 
 Having (rn)<=(select 
            round(count(mt.medicaid_no)*0.03) as percentt
      from membership mt)`