# Querying data with different conditions on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with date column and 3 different other columns: X, Y, Z.
I want the get the date, X and Y for last month and Z column the sum for all the previous dates.

This is the query that I worked on:

```
SELECT date,
  x,
  y,
  (
    SELECT z
    FROM Table
    WHERE date < DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE())
  )
FROM Table
WHERE date BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND
  DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE());
```

Here's some sample data:

[image]

And here's how I want the the result:

```
date       | X | Y | Z  
-----------+---+---+---  
2019-08-01 | 8 | 8 | 14 
2019-08-02 | 2 | 2 | 14
```

The date, X and Y only for last month and Z the sum of all time (1+1+2+8+2=14).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do what you want:

```
select t.date, t.x, t.y, t.new_z
from (select t.*, sum(z) over () as new_z,
             rank() over (order by year(date) desc, month(date) desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Actually, you could also do:

```
select top (1) with ties t.date, t.x, t.y, sum(z) over () as z
from t
order by year(date) desc, month(date) desc;
```

Comment: the sub query returns more then one value and that one gets just one

Comment: @chawky . . . Your original question seemed quite clear that you wanted one row.  But I fixed the answer to get rows from the most recent month.

Comment: it worked but can you explain what you did there  ?

Comment: how did it get only the date for last month ? i dont see a condition for that , and what does with ties do ?

Comment: @chawky . . . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you're missing a few things.

<s>SELECT max(OrderDate), CustomerID, EmployeeID,
        ( select sum(ShipperID) from [Orders]
            WHERE OrderDate <= '1996-07-15'
        )
    FROM [Orders]
    WHERE OrderDate <= '1996-07-15';</s>

<s>SELECT OrderDate, CustomerID, EmployeeID,
        ( select sum(ShipperID) from [Orders] inside
            WHERE inside.OrderDate <= outside.OrderDate
        )
    FROM [Orders] outside
    WHERE OrderDate between '1996-07-11' and '1996-07-15';</s>

```
WITH SumZ as (select sum(ShipperID) as zColumn from [Orders] inside
    WHERE inside.OrderDate <= '1996-07-15')

SELECT OrderDate, CustomerID, EmployeeID, SumZ.zColumn
FROM [Orders] outside, SumZ
WHERE OrderDate between '1996-07-11' and '1996-07-15';
```

I used a different dataset, but to the same effect.*

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in

Since you want all the `z` columns to be the same, using a `WITH` (actually called a "common table expression" or CTE) prevents your query from running the same sub-query multiple times. Since there's nothing to `JOIN` with, I didn't do one, but you can `JOIN` on a CTE just like any other table, view, etc.

Further readin on CTEs:
https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/
and
[When to use Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740748/when-to-use-common-table-expression-cte)

It queries the `Orders` table based on the "largest" `Date`, gets the data from 3 columns of that row, and sums the values of a 4th column based on the same criteria as the outer query.

*In my example, the data is just there for an example and doesn't mean anything useful. <s>Also, I simplified the date selection, since the data I used didn't actually include a `Date` column.</s> Turns out, it is a `Date` column.

Comment: it retuns one result , mine can have mutliple results , just in the example i gave there is just ons line with the date of last month , if there are a lot of lines like that it will have multiple results

Comment: @chawky, is the last column still supposed to be 14 for both results or is it supposed to be 16 for one? Or is it now supposed to be 16 for both?

Comment: the last column is the sum of z for all the dates so 14 for both

Comment: @chawky, but 14 is no longer the sum of `z` for all the dates.

Comment: 1+1+2+8+2 is the sum

Comment: @chawky, sorry, I guess I read/remembered that incorrectly. I should have done the math again. I'm no longer sure why I thought 14 was wrong. The math you have on the answer is outdated, though, since that's still saying 12.

Answer (score 1):

This checks for last month. Updated for new sample data.

```
select
(select t2.x from sample t2 where (month(t2.date) = month(getdate()) - 1) and year(t2.date) = year(getdate())
and t2.date = (select max(t3.date) from sample t3)) as x,
(select t2.y from sample t2 where (month(t2.date) = month(getdate()) - 1) and year(t2.date) = year(getdate())
and t2.date = (select max(t3.date) from sample t3)) as y,
    sum(t1.z) as z
from sample t1
```

Comment: i got this error : Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @chawky I updated the query for the updated sample data.