# Recursive self referenced table to flat structure

Tags: sql-server, recursion, self-referencing-table

```
Entity
---------
ID
TypeAID
TypeBID
```

`TypeAID` and `TypeBID` are nullable fields where row can have one, both or none values entered, and both `IDs` are pointing to same table `Entity.ID` (self reference).

Is there any way to go recursive through 3 level deep structure and get flat structure of `parent -> child`, `parent -> grandchild`, `child -> grandchild` relations?

This is example where first table is normal hierarchy and second is desired flat output.

Data:

```
Row   ID    TypeAID    TypeBID
1     A     NULL       NULL
2     B     NULL       NULL
3     C     A          NULL
4     D     B          C
5     E     NULL       C
```

Desired result:

```
Row   Parent    Child
1     A         C
2     A         D
3     A         E
4     B         D
5     C         D
6     C         E
```

Comment: Yes this is possible. If you want to learn how you need to provide some details. Like sample data and desired output. [mcve]

Comment: Any ideas where to start?

Comment: You have to use Common Table Expression https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740748/when-to-use-common-table-expression-cte

Comment: @SeanLange I've added example input/output.

Comment: Pictures of data are nearly worthless. [Why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)? You need a recursive cte to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CTE:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Id CHAR(1), TypeAId CHAR(1), TypeBId CHAR(1))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    ('A', NULL, NULL),
    ('B', NULL, NULL),
    ('C', 'A', NULL),
    ('D', 'B', 'C'),
    ('E', NULL, 'C')

-- All entities flattened
;WITH l1 AS (
    SELECT t.TypeAId AS Parent, t.Id AS Child
    FROM @t t
    WHERE t.TypeAId IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT t.TypeBId AS Parent, t.Id AS Child
    FROM @t t
    WHERE t.TypeBId IS NOT NULL)

-- Join l1 with itself
,l2 AS (
    SELECT l1.Parent, l2.Child
    FROM l1 l1
    INNER JOIN l1 l2 ON l2.Parent = l1.Child)

SELECT * FROM l1
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM l2
ORDER BY Parent
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for any number of levels:

```
DECLARE @t table
(
    ID char(1)
    , TypeAID char(1)
    , TypeBID char(1)
)

INSERT INTO @t (ID, TypeAID, TypeBID)
VALUES
('A', NULL, NULL)
, ('B', NULL, NULL)
, ('C', 'A', NULL)
, ('D', 'B', 'C')
, ('E', NULL, 'C')
;

WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT
        Parent
        , ID Child
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                ID
                , TypeAID
                , TypeBID
            FROM @t
        ) D
        UNPIVOT
        (
            Parent FOR TypeID IN (
                [TypeAID]
                , [TypeBID]
            )
        ) U
)
,

cte2
AS
(
    SELECT
        Parent
        , Child
    FROM cte

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        cte1.Parent
        , cte2.Child
    FROM
        cte2 cte1
        JOIN cte cte2 ON cte1.Child = cte2.Parent
)

SELECT
    Parent
    , Child
FROM cte2
ORDER BY
    Parent
    , Child
```