# Remove same set of values from 2 columns in sql

Tags: sql

I have 4 columns in result from sql query from table TCD.

```
DateTime           Cust_id    User_id   Sequence
------------------------------------------------
9/15/2023 6:32      154389      2293        1
9/15/2023 6:32      154389      2293        0
9/15/2023 6:14      154389      2226        2
9/15/2023 6:12      154389      2226        1
9/15/2023 6:14      154389      2226        0
```

[table TCD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XwWA.png)

I need to remove same set of values from columns from Cust_id & User_id and keep the set which has maximum value of 4th column sequence in table using a SQL query.

Comment: Please put more effort in your question. Read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

```
MariaDB [mytest]> select * from TCD;
+---------------------+---------+---------+----------+
| DateTime            | Cust_id | User_id | Sequence |
+---------------------+---------+---------+----------+
| 2023-08-09 21:07:24 | 154389  | 2293    |        1 |
| 2023-08-09 21:07:24 | 154389  | 2293    |        0 |
| 2023-08-09 21:07:24 | 154389  | 2226    |        2 |
| 2023-08-09 21:07:24 | 154389  | 2226    |        1 |
| 2023-08-09 21:07:24 | 154389  | 2226    |        0 |
+---------------------+---------+---------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [mytest]> delete from TCD where Sequence <> (select MAX(Sequence) from TCD);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.003 sec)

MariaDB [mytest]> select * from TCD;
+---------------------+---------+---------+----------+
| DateTime            | Cust_id | User_id | Sequence |
+---------------------+---------+---------+----------+
| 2023-08-09 21:07:24 | 154389  | 2226    |        2 |
+---------------------+---------+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [mytest]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the CTE, use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to assign a unique row number to each row. After this numbering, in your main query, from the CTE, filter out the duplicates by selecting only the rows with row number 1.

```
WITH RankedRows AS (
    SELECT 
        DateTime,
        Cust_id,
        User_id,
        Sequence,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Cust_id, User_id ORDER BY Sequence DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
        TCD
)
SELECT 
    DateTime,
    Cust_id,
    User_id,
    Sequence
FROM 
    RankedRows
WHERE 
    rn = 1;
```

Comment: What `CTE`? Please improve your answer and show a complete and correct query rather than a meaningless part of it.  If you can't due to the poor description in the question, better let the author clarify their requirements before answering.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Provided complete query.

For a deeper understanding of the context, I recommend reviewing this StackOverflow discussion on Common Table Expressions (CTEs): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740748/when-to-use-common-table-expression-cte

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` to get the maximum value of Sequence for Cust_id & User_id

```
SELECT
    Cust_id,
    User_id,
    MAX(Sequence) AS Max_Sequence
FROM
    TCD
GROUP BY
    Cust_id,
    User_id;
```

Then, do an inner join with the main table to preserve only these rows. The final query looks like the following,

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TCD t
JOIN (
  SELECT Cust_id, User_id, MAX(Sequence) AS Max_Sequence
  FROM TCD
  GROUP BY Cust_id, User_id
) AS max_rows
ON t.Cust_id = max_rows.Cust_id
AND t.User_id = max_rows.User_id
AND t.Sequence = max_rows.Max_Sequence;
```