# Do CTE's materialize a computation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've written a UDF for re-use in an ETL cleansing process and am trying to quantify which approach is better. I'm wondering if my assumption is correct that a CTE will compute a value and materialize it when called, but am concerned it may just abstract the computation being run multiple times.

Sample code to consider:

```
with cte as (select 'This is a test////////$$$$$$$$' as val),
    cteReplaceDollar as (select replace(val, '$', '') as val from cte),
    cteReplaceSlash as (select replace(val, '/', '') as val from cteReplaceDollar),
    cteReplaceEmpty as (select replace(val, ' ', '') as val from cteReplaceSlash)
select 
    * 
from 
    cteReplaceEmpty
where
    val = 'Thisisatest' and
    val > '' and
    isnumeric(val) = 0;
```

Is this performing the replace 3 times (an optimistic assumption) or 18 times (a pessimistic assumption)? Basically, does it materialize the intermediate steps similar to variable assignment, or does it work as a generator expression in which each step is performed for every reference of the value and every value in the collection?

Comment: [This SO question seems related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090037/t-sql-cte-materializing-techniques-not-working-on-sql-server-2012).  The general answer appears to be that SQL Server might materialize a CTE, depending on how you write it.

Comment: I think the answer is: It depends... But this is not enough to place an answer ;-) You tell the engine **what** you want, but not **how to act**. The engine will find the best execution plan (at least: tries to find). The same query can lead to quite different plans depending on things you cannot know in advance. Sometimes I miss something like `WITH cte FORCE PRECOMPUTE AS(blah)` ...

Comment: @Shnugo I try to follow that principle of WHAT vs HOW, but in this case I was specifically performance-tuning in the hopes of improving the processing of an existing function, so I had to be concerned with the HOW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, SQL Server doesn't materialise CTE, as opposed to, say, Postgres.

You can confirm it by examining the actual execution plan for your query.
I'd recommend SentryOne Plan Explorer, it is a great tool.

https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer

I expect to see 7 calls to `replace` in your example.

---

Well, I miscalculated. The real answer is:

you should check the actual execution plan.

In your example it looks like this:

[image: Filer]

9 calls to `replace` in `Filter` operator.

[image: Compute scalar]

plus 3 calls in `Compute Scalar` operator.

12 in total.

---

So, we confirmed that SQL Server didn't materialise CTE in this example. (It was SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition)

Some further reading:

[What's the difference between a CTE and a Temp Table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/13112/57105)

[Is there a performance difference between CTE , Sub-Query, Temporary Table or Table Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11169550/4116017)

[Use of With Clause in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2855940/4116017)

There is a suggestion for Microsoft to add a `Materialize` hint for CTE, similar to what Oracle offers: [T-SQL Common Table Expression "Materialize" Option](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32642629-t-sql-common-table-expression-materialize-option)

Comment: Thanks for all the good reference material. I use SentryOne Plan Explorer a ton for work, and I didn't think to use it to analyze the plan for expressions.

I guess I should re-think how I apply these principles, as I used CTE's frequently to compartmentalize code re-use, and hoped it would eagerly evaluate and store in TempDB rather than dynamically present it everytime it was called. Ah well, learn from your mistakes.

Thanks again.